# Laravel CORS error with credential

Tags: angular, laravel, api, cors, laravel-5.5

I use angular 4 as frontend and laravel (homestead mydomain.test) as backend.
below errors show in chrome browser when I want to send the cookie from angular 4 to laravel API backend:

barryvdh/laravel-cors configuration file (cors.php config file):

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => true,
'allowedOrigins' => ['http://localhost:4200'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type','Accept'],
'allowedMethods' => ['GET','POST','PUT', 'PATCH', 'OPTION'],
'exposedHeaders' => ['Content-Disposition', 'x-total-count', 'x-filename', '*'],
'maxAge' => 0,
'hosts' => ['*'],
```

angular 4 requests:

```
refreshToken(){

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()})
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.post(API_DOMAIN + 'refresh', JSON.stringify({}), options)
      .map(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response.json());
          return response.json()
        },
      )
  }
```

browser errors:

`Failed to load http://mydomian.test/api/refresh: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: You should not set * in allow headers.You must specify all allowed request headers like ``'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type,Accept']``

Comment: @DevangNaghera I added allowedHeaders but the error still exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by:
Create proxy.conf.json in the root of Angular app. Put an object with routes inside:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://mydomian.test/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I just have /api defined here because all my backend URIs are inside api.php. All calls that look like http://localhost:4200/api/someitems/1 will be proxied to http://mydomian.test/api/someitems/1. 
Then edit package.json and change the value of start inside scripts to ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json. Now npm run start will start with proxy. The problem I had with this proxy is that it resolves your URL (http://mydomian.test/) to an IP. When it calls Laravel with just an IP the nginx server does not know what to do because it must receive a domain name. nginx allows multiple website on the same IP so it must receive a domain name or to have a default website to which it redirects all calls those have no domain name. In case this is still not fixed in Angular's proxy go to /etc/nginx/sites-available on the Laravel machine, you'll have a mydomian.test config file there. It has listen 80; line there, change it to listen 80 default;.

Now you can change the API_DOMAIN variable to http://localhost:4200 (or remove it all together) and disable the CORS.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any laravel cors .just simply put this code into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "authorization,language,Content-Type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Comment: my web app implemented on localhost! added these code inside htaccess but error still exist!